# How to add LinearExpr in Python for Google OR-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

In C++ I can add constraints as follows

```
for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++)
{
    LinearExpr eq1;
    eq1 += Tc - TET[t - 1];
    solver->MakeRowConstraint(eq1 >= 0.0);
}
```

How to do the same in Python3?

Solver used: SCIP

Tried `eq1 = solver.LinearExpr()` in python to initialize a linear expression to a variable

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have with your attempt? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I do not even know which solver you are using (linear solver, routing library, cp-sat)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can use the `Add` method instead of `MakeRowConstraint`.

Below is an attempt that takes an educated guess at creating a full [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on your original C++ snippet:

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

# Create the linear solver with the GLOP backend.
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('GLOP')

# Define your parameters.
T = 10
Tc = 15  # Let's use a value for Tc that ensures all constraints can be satisfied.
TET = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# Create a list to hold the variables we'll create.
eqs = []

# Loop through the range.
for t in range(1, T+1):
    # Create a variable.
    eq = solver.NumVar(0.0, solver.infinity(), f'eq_{t}')

    # Remember the variable.
    eqs.append(eq)

    # Add the constraint to the solver.
    solver.Add(eq == Tc - TET[t - 1])
    solver.Add(eq >= 0)

# Create an objective function (for example, maximize sum of all eqs).
objective = solver.Objective()
for eq in eqs:
    objective.SetCoefficient(eq, 1)
objective.SetMaximization()

# Solve the system.
status = solver.Solve()

# Print solution.
if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
    print('Solution:')
    print('Objective value =', solver.Objective().Value())
    for t in range(1, T+1):
        print(f'eq_{t} =', solver.LookupVariable(f'eq_{t}').solution_value())
else:
    print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')
```

**Output:**

```
Solution:
Objective value = 95.0
eq_1 = 14.0
eq_2 = 13.0
eq_3 = 12.0
eq_4 = 11.0
eq_5 = 10.0
eq_6 = 9.0
eq_7 = 8.0
eq_8 = 7.0
eq_9 = 6.0
eq_10 = 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed example. I got stuck here now

```
`LinearExpr eq4;`                                            // ?
`for (int p = 1; p <= P; p++)`                         // for p in range(P)
  `eq4 += TP[p - 1];`                                       // ?
`solver->MakeRowConstraint(eq4 >= 1.0);`  // solver.Add(eq4 >= 1)
```
`solver.LinearExpr()` not worked.

Comment: Solver.Maximize(sum(eqs)) ?

Comment: Thanks, `sum(eqs)` worked. `eq4=[]` `for p in range(P)` `eq4.append(TP[p-1])` `solver.Add(sum(eq4) >= 1)`